# get list from api call show me undefined in componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components

i am new to react js , i have an api which render a list of products for me , i am getting this list and making it in state in componentDidMount but when i triy to render this list nothing is shown .
when i console.log the list inside render() method it shows many times but the first time is undefined . I thought maybe it is because the async call of the api but i can't figure out any solution .
this is my componentDidMount function:

```
 componentDidMount= async() => {
  
  const optionName = this.props.data.name
  const optionProducts = await product.getProductsByOption(optionName)
  this.setState({optionProducts})

}
```

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: This is how it works. Either proceed from the fact that the list is initially empty, or move the request to a parent.

Comment: As the above comment mentions this is expected behaviour. You could use the coalesce operator (??) to make the list appear as empty if it is undefined `this.setState(optionProducts ?? [])`.